# Alt-Gr issue in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, keyboard, alt, altgr

There seems to be a pretty significant bug in Excel concerning EU keyboards with an <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key that is used to access rather important symbols such as €, #, and @. It is simply impossible to type any of these symbols directly either in the cell or the formula bar. The irony of it being a Microsoft keyboard doesn't escape attention either.

Is there anyone that have solved this issue? I have a user that keeps on getting this problem. We have tried to reactivate the process by running `C:\Windows\System32\ctfmon.exe` but this didn't help.

The strange thing is that the <kbd>AltGr</kbd> button works when using Excel inside remote desktop app, and it works fine locally when not using Excel.

All help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried Ctrl + Alt as the alternative to Alt Gr these should have the same function? Please let us know what happens if you try this.

Comment: ctrl+alt dosent work for some reason.  found out he has an older version then me, tried to update it. but hes on the enterprise channel so no avaible update. trying to get him over to "current channel" and see if this helps.
With a new update the problem may be fixed, but not sure.

Answer (score 0):

The <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key should work fine in Excel. However, the keyboard locale can sometimes be a problem and you can try switching from the current language to see if this helps.

Nonetheless, if this won't work for you, you can try one of the other work-arounds to get the same outcome. For example <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> should serve the same function as <kbd>AltGr</kbd> on Windows 10.

If this also won't work for you, you can always use Windows Alt Codes to type characters directly. For example, the € symbol can be entered using <kbd>Alt</kbd> + 0128 or the Copywrite symbol © is Alt + 0169

For a full map of alt codes have a look at [alt-codes.net](https://www.alt-codes.net/).

I hope that this helps.

Comment: ctrl+alt dosent work for some reason. found out he has an older version then me, tried to update it. but hes on the enterprise channel so no avaible update. trying to get him over to "current channel" and see if this helps. With a new update the problem may be fixed, but not sure.
havent tried the alt code, but i think it have been tried out.

Comment: I'd like to note here that I was having some issues with some keys in Excel using a remote connection(VNC), not AltGr, but similar. After multiple tries, the culprit was the Bloomberg Terminal Add-in on Excel, specifically the HotKey Manager, disabling it in Excel, fixed it. Thanks for posting your answer!

Answer (score 0):

Found out that the issue was when he used Excell local. No RDP or Remote Desktop app running, same issue.

He had the Bloomberg terminal install with excell addin. uninstalled this app and then the Alt-Gr was back.

The wierd thing is that when we got Bloomberg installed again, the Alt-Gr button is Still working.
So root couse = still unknown, but possible related to the Bloomberg app.